# Unit test for Ping / PingReply - Mocking?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest, rhino-mocks

I was hoping to find a way to unit test my pinging functionality or be able to Mock it with RhinoMocks

Here is a simple example of the code I would like to be able to unit test:

```
public PingReply PingMachine(string machineName)
{
    Ping ping = new Ping();
    return ping.Send(machineName);
}

public bool IsOnline(string machineName)
{
    var reply = PingMachine(machineName);
    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Besides Creating my own IPing interface and making Ping into IPing and adding another constructor and bunch of work for that, is there a way to easily unit test this, or should I not waste my time with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you already know a good approach to making your code testable: Depend on abstractions. Don't use a `Ping`, use `IPing`, and have the `IPing` be provided via constructor to the class that's going to use it.

Look into an IOC container like [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) to make your life easier, especially if you're wiring up a lot of dependencies.

As for whether you should or not, my answer to "should I make this code testable and write tests for it" is always a resounding **YES**.

Think of it like this: You have this method, `IsOnline(string machineName)`. Let's say you're writing code somewhere else, and you want to test that code. But that code uses `IsOnline`! Suddenly, testing it just got harder. If you could mock your ping providing class, testing it would be a breeze.

Comment: Is there an IPing anywhere? I use the SystemWrapper from Codeplex but it doesn't have one in there, which means I'd have to roll my own from what it looks like

Comment: Unfortunately, that's generally the case when dealing with older parts of the framework. I've had to write wrappers for the System.IO.* file system stuff several times.

Comment: If i create an IPing interface and Mock the Send(string, int) method. What should it return? If i just return PingReply i can not mock the return value because PingReply's constructor is internal.

Comment: Okay... now i created an addition interface `IPingReply` and mocked the `PingReply` functions that i need... phew...

Answer (score 2):

The only difficulty I can see in your sample is `new Ping()` call. At some point you might want to verify that `Send` was called with correct data, at the moment this is close to impossible. Creation of objects is usually abstracted with [Factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), so if you indeed run into issues with `new Ping()`, I suggest delegating ping creation to such factory and inject it into your tested class. Your code could look like this:

```
// some minor injection work
public TestedClass(IPingFactory pingsFactory)
{
    this.pingsFactory = pingsFactory;
}

public PingReply PingMachine(string machineName)
{
    IPing ping = pingsFactory.Create();
    return ping.Send(machineName);
}
```